# Apache Indexing question

Tags: apache, user-interface, indexing

Wondering how I might achieve this look with Apache's Indexing?  Is there a module I can download?

[alt text http://www.aaphid.com/uploads/Screen.png](http://www.aaphid.com/uploads/Screen.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The look that you have posted is the Firefox FTP browser. to achieve a look similar with just apache take a look at mod_autoindex (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_autoindex.html) particularly:

HeaderName
and
AddIconByType

and with a bit of CSS you can achieve this look.

Comment: @lrudor - yep I noticed it only looks this way in Firefox.  Thanks for the info!